# Error occurred while installing zenity

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt-get, zenity

I was trying to install zenity, from the command

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

and the result its

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zenity : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It seems to fall into a dead loop, every dependencies package that relate to webkit2gtk failed to install, always same error occurred

I tried apt-get update/upgrade, aptitude and install by deb, its doesn't work or I don't know how to correctly use them
I tried uncomment all link inside the /etc/apt/source.list, but its doesn’t seems work, did I do right?

I am a linux newer, my device its raspberry pi3, running in raspbian 8 
Can anybody help me to resolve this problem? very very appreciation for you

Answer (score -1):

Solved, because libtext-iconv-perl this package is depending on old perl-base 5.20, download and install manually in [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libtext-iconv-perl)